# sails js many to many record insertion error

Tags: node.js, sails.js, postman, waterline

I have two models: Users and InstalledApps. Models are like this:

```
//Users Model
attributes:{
name: 'string',
age: 'string',
installedApps:{
  collection: 'installedApps',
  via: 'users'
 }
}
```

My InstalledApps model is like this:

```
attributes:{
 deviceID : 'string',
 users:{
  collection:'users',
  via:'installedApps'
 }
}
```

Now I have already created the user with id 1 and 2.
But when I insert data in InstalledApps via postman like this:

```
{
 "users": [1,2],
 "deviceID": "123456",
}
```

It pops an error: `Unknown rule: default`. I don't know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your models are fine. Have you made sure you're posting the data as JSON? In the `Body` tab in Postman, select `raw` and then change from `Text` to `JSON (application/json)`. Remove the surplus comma after `"123456"` and your request should go through without problems. Also, make sure you're doing a `POST` request to the `/installedApps` route, e.g. `http://localhost:1337/installedApps`.

I tested this with the model definitions you posted in a fresh Sails.js app, getting `installedApps` entries inserted correctly with associations to `users` entries.

Comment: actually i was sending 'autoUpdateAt ' also in the json, which was causing error. I think 'autoUpdatedAt' should not be sent.

Comment: @DevendraVerma That's right – `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are handled automatically by default (configurable globally in `config/models.js` or for a particular model in the model file). Glad you got the issue resolved. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you made your models wrong.
You should use http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/through-associations .
Then you should have 3 models. USER, APP, INSTALLED_APPS.

Your user model will get:

```
//Users Model
attributes:{
name: 'string',
age: 'string',
installedApps:{
  collection: 'APP',
  via: 'user',
through: 'installedApps'
 }
}
```

and your APP model:

```
//APP Model
attributes:{
device: 'string',
installedApps:{
  collection: 'APP',
  via: 'app',
through: 'installedApps'
 }
}
```

and finally your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
  //INSTALLED_APPS Model
    attributes:{
    user: {
      model: 'user'
    },
    app: {
      model: 'app'
    }
    }
```

Then you will just use simple create of INSTALLED APP for every user/app or blueprint http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/add-to

Hope it helps.